# How to run code that needs too much RAM on OpenShift?

Tags: python, django, openshift

I have a problem with OpenShift. Currently I am trying to add [django_geoip](https://github.com/futurecolors/django-geoip) to my django app. However, when I try to initialize its database, OpenShift kills it. I think it is needing too much memory.
If I run update code `./manage.py geoip_update`(I also tried running with nohup), this is the output:

```
Downloading zipfile from ipgeobase.ru...
INFO:import:Downloading zipfile from ipgeobase.ru...
Extracting files...
INFO:import:Extracting files...
Updating locations...
INFO:import:Updating locations...
Updating CIDR...
INFO:import:Updating CIDR...
61%
```

After 61% of CIDR update it crashes. If I am following log or am logged in through ssh, it disconects me:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/ruby_compat.rb:30:in `select': closed stream (IOError)
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/ruby_compat.rb:30:in `io_select'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/packet_stream.rb:75:in `available_for_read?'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/packet_stream.rb:87:in `next_packet'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:183:in `block in poll_message'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:178:in `loop'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:178:in `poll_message'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:461:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:222:in `preprocess'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:206:in `process'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `block in loop'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `loop'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `loop'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/ssh_helpers.rb:198:in `block in ssh_ruby'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:215:in `start'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/ssh_helpers.rb:173:in `ssh_ruby'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/commands/tail.rb:40:in `tail'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/commands/tail.rb:21:in `run'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:294:in `execute'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:285:in `block (3 levels) in to_commander'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/runner.rb:421:in `run_active_command'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/command_runner.rb:72:in `run!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/delegates.rb:12:in `run!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.36.4/lib/rhc/cli.rb:37:in `start'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.36.4/bin/rhc:20:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'
```

I only guess it was heavy memory usage. I tried to empty my database and deleted log files so that I was sure it was not capacity problem(disk quota exceeded).
My question is: **How do I run this command to make it work? May I somehow limit needed resources?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out it was caused by geoip creating `django_geoip_iprange` table, that has around ~218 000 records. Geoip probably loads all these ips into memory and then stores them to database. I was able to import table `django_geoip_iprange` from localhost, so django_geoip should be fully functional now.
Additionally, I should be able to use [`ulimit`](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) to limit resources required. Did not test that yet.